# Is a constant function $f(x)=5$ both convex and concave?

Tags: functions, convex-analysis

Is a constant function $f(x)=5$ both convex and concave? Or neither convex nor concave?

Comment: All functions of the form $ax+b$ are both convex and concave.

Comment: It's concave and convex, but neither strictly concave nor strictly convex.

Answer (score 1):

$f’(x) = 0$

$f’’(x) = 0$.

If $f’’(x) \geq 0$ , $f$ is convex.

If $f’’(x) \leq 0$ , $f$ is concave.

If $f’’(x) = 0$ , $f$ is both convex and concave.

In this case , $f’’(x) = 0$. So , $f$ is both convex and concave.

Comment: You should change $\gt$ with $\ge$.

Comment: Sorry , @TigranHarutyunyan

Answer (score 0):

These definitions are from Wikipedia:

> A real-valued function defined on an n-dimensional interval is called convex (or convex downward or concave upward) if the line segment between any two points on the graph of the function lies above or on the graph.

> A real-valued function defined on an n-dimensional interval is called concave if the line segment between any two points on the graph of the function lies below or on the graph.

We can conclude from this definition that $f(x)=C$ (constant function) is both convex and concave, because the line segment between any two points on the graph of $f$ lies on the graph.